# How do I add an hour column in character varying format to a date field also in character varying format in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime

I've tried this approach but keep getting errors. A value in the hour_column would look like this: 15. The date_column looks like this: 2021-09-24

```
cast(date_column as time) + INTERVAL '1 HOUR' * cast(hour_column as time)
```

Comment: If `date_column` is really a date string then the cast should be `cast(date_column as date)`. This: `INTERVAL '1 HOUR' * cast(hour_column as time)` could go wrong in different ways. You need to update the question  with the examples of the actual data you are using.

Comment: I have updated the question with the way the data is formatted in both columns as requested.

Comment: `select cast('2021-09-24' as date) + INTERVAL '1 HOUR' * 15; 2021-09-24 15:00:00`. In your case: `select cast(date_column as date) + INTERVAL '1 HOUR' * hour_column;`

Comment: The challenge with I get with that is an error saying ' operator does not exist: interval * character varying '. That's why I casted the hour_column. Even casting it as a date brings up the same error.

Comment: Try: `INTERVAL '1 HOUR' * hour_column::integer;`. Long term you will be better of changing `date_column` to the `date` type and `hour_column` to `integer` type or `numeric` if you have decimal hours.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you just need to set only the hour value (hour gets from column) on the DateTime column of the table.

Sample Query:

```
with table1 as (
    select '2022-04-06 08:19:54.230' as pdatetime, '12' as phour
    union all 
    select '2022-04-06 14:47:11.412' as pdatetime, '18' as phour
    union all 
    select '2022-04-06 20:26:37.106' as pdatetime, '22' as phour
)
select 
    pdatetime::timestamp - 
    (extract(hour from pdatetime::timestamp)::text || ' hour')::interval + 
    (phour || ' hour')::interval  
from table1

-- Return: 
2022-04-06 12:19:54.230
2022-04-06 18:47:11.412
2022-04-06 22:26:37.106
```